# Initializing static array in a function in C

Tags: c

Can a static array that is declared in `main` be initialized/mutated in a function?

I tried the code below but it returns a seg fault.

```
void initialize(int **p, int a, int b) 
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<a; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<b; ++j)
            p[i][j] = j;
    }
}

int m = 5;
int n = 5;
int arr[m][n];
int **A = &arr[0][0];


initialize(A, m, n);
```

---

EDIT:

I found a good explanation of this issue here:

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

Comment: `A` is **not** `int**` Whomever told you they were synonymous is wrong.

Comment: That code should fail to compile: http://ideone.com/OCCB95.

Comment: @WhozCraig. I edited the code. I actually created a double pointer to the static array.

Comment: @Zaphod that makes absolutely no difference to my comment. `arr` likewise isn't `int**` delaying that inevitability isn't going to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an two dimensional array not a pointer to pointer. You will have to change the function argument type.

```
void initialize( int a, int b , int p[][b] ) 
{
    ...
```

Since you have to define the size for the array `p`, the arguments `a` and `b` are declared first and then `b` is used to determine the size.

Comment: What if I declare and initialize a double pointer to the static array?

Comment: @Zaphod stop thinking a pointer-to-pointer is synonymous to an array of arrays. They're NOT the same. When looking at a pointer, consider it as a "pointer to a sequence of X" where X is the type of the pointer. A pointer to pointer therefore is "a pointer to a sequence of **pointers**. `Type arr[n][m]` is no such sequence. This answer is one correct way to pass an array of arrays to a function.  In your question `arr` is an array of arrays. That does *not* express as a pointer-to-pointer when passed to a function, and as I said, however you concluded they were synonymous it is simply wrong.

Comment: @2501. If I want to, could I do `int p[a][b]` instead of `int p[][b]`? Why the latter?

Comment: @Zaphod You can do both as long as every, but the first, dimension is declared.

Comment: @2501. Why must the first dimension not be declared?

Comment: @Zaphod: From compiler's point of view both `int p[a][b]` and `int p[][b]` are translated to `int (*p)[b]` anyway, that is first dimension is simply ignored, thus there no point putting it, moreover it may be misleading for someone who doesn't know C that well.

Comment: @Zaphod: In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are both interpreted as `T *a`; they declare `a` as a *pointer* to `T`, not as an array of `T`.  Thus, `T a[][N]` is equivalent to `T (*a)[N]`; `a` is a pointer to an `N`-element array of `T`.  That's why you don't need to specify the innermost dimension; it isn't used in this context.  However, if you do use it in the declaration of `a`, it must be declared *before* `a` - `foo( int a, int b, int p[a][b] )`.

Comment: @Zaphod As for why do you need dimensions in the first place, a 2d array is contiguous in memory and you need to know how many places to skip when you iterate trough the outer dimension, and the size of the inner dimension gives you that information. Try it on paper.

Comment: @2501 fyi, that "places to skip" verb-age has a shorter vernacular. It is called the *stride* of an array dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the warnings in your compiler and you'll get this:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘initialize’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

As a result, you receive a seg. fault.

You need to change the prototype of your function to this:

```
void initialize(int a, int b, int p[][b]);
```

and the calling of the function will be:

```
initialize(m, n, A);
```

Comment: The calling of function will also change :)

Comment: The OP specifies that he's declaring `A` within `main`, so it's not static.  Besides, a VLA *cannot* be declared static or at file scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can, wouldn't be very useful if they couldn't.

However you've encountered a problem with the way you're trying to decay arrays into pointers there. What you've declared in `main` is a *two-dimensional array* - a single block of memory that happens to be indexed through a combination of the two indices (translated at compile-time). You're trying to decay it as though it was an *array of pointers to arrays* - meaning that within `initialize`, you're dereferencing the pointer, to try to get a pointer, and then dereferencing that to get a slot. Since a two-dimensional array actually describes a single block of memory, two layers of *pointer* indirection won't work to access it. You need to decay it to a type involving only one level of pointer indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
initialize(A, m, n);
void initialize(int **p, int a, int b)
```

to

```
initialize(n, A, m);
void initialize( int b, int p[][b], int a)
```

When you are passing a multidimensional array to a function, the first array dimension does not have to be specified. However the second(and subsequent) dimensions must be provided to the function.

Comment: don't do this, since it assumes that b is always 5.

Comment: @G.Samaras: You are right, I saw OP has initialized it to 5 so specified the second dimension as `5`.

Comment: I suspected that you did. The edit you made won't compile, since b is not known. (that's why you got a -1 from someone).